# ndk-build with sqlite library error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk

I am creating an android application which is having native C code along with sqlite database.
When I do a ndk-build from my jni folder,I am getting the following error.

```
undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
peard.c:(.text+0x588): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
peard.c:(.text+0x5f8): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
peard.c:(.text+0x668): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
peard.c:(.text+0x6d8): undefined reference to `sqlite3_prepare_v2'
peard.c:(.text+0x720): undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_count'
peard.c:(.text+0x734): undefined reference to `sqlite3_step'
peard.c:(.text+0x774): undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_text'
peard.c:(.text+0x78c): undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_name'
peard.c:(.text+0x800): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
```

I tried to run along with -lsqlite3 command also,but doesn't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build or install `sqlite3` (and all other non standard libraries you project depends on) **for android**, and the build your project with the `-L` and `-I` parameters pointing to the arm version of you sqlite libraries and headers.

Comment: With my Make file,when i do a "make" command I am able to execute properly.When i do a ndk-build it's not fine.Can you give me example for the ndk-build command line with -I and -L option?

Comment: ndk-build -Lsqlite3 -Isqlite3.h. Is this correct? But I am not getting it still.

Comment: Where is your `sqlite` targeting android installed? For instance, if you have the libraries in '/opt/android/sqlite/lib' you need to pass `-L/opt/android/sqlite/lib` as parameter to gcc. This is usually done in Android.mk with the variable `LOCAL_CFLAGS`

Comment: I have kept my sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h which i got from sqlite-amalgamation source code inside the jni folder of my android project along with android.mk file.I dont have any separate library like what you are telling.     In my android.mk file I have given like this:   LOCAL_CFLAGS += $(common_sqlite_flags).Please guide me further

Comment: Then add your `sqlite3.c` to the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

Comment: Check if there are functions like 'sqlite3_exec' in the `sqlite3.c` you use. Check in the build output if `sqlite3.o` is really built.

Comment: sorry I have the functions and sqlite.o its there in my project objs folder

Comment: Which command you are talikng about?For the "ndk-build" command it is showing the above error.Is there any options to add with ndk-build command to execute to refer sqlite library?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding sqlite3.c source  file to my dependency files list in my Android.mk file.Special thanks to hirschhomsalz.

Narain.