# How to add a sqlite library in Eclipse java edition?

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x, undefined-reference

I'm working with a cocos2dx c++ android project that I compile with Eclipse (java edition).
Everything has worked great until I try to use sqlite3.

I'm pretty sure the code is correct.

```
sqlite3 *pdb = NULL;
int result;

std::string path = FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath();
path.append("mydb.db");

FILE* file = fopen(path.c_str(), "r");
if (file == nullptr) {
    CCLOG("no such file");
    long size = 0;
    const char* data = (char*) FileUtils::getInstance()->getFileData("mydb.db", "rb", &size);
    file = fopen(path.c_str(), "wb");
    fwrite(data, size, 1, file);
    CC_SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(data);
}

result = sqlite3_open(path.c_str(),&pdb);
if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    CCLOG("OPEN FAILED");
else
    CCLOG("OPEN WORKED");

char **re;
int r,c;

sqlite3_get_table(pdb,"select * from mytable", &re, &r, &c, NULL);
CCLOG("num of rows is %d, num of columns is %d", r, c);
```

I get these errors

**"undefined reference to 'sqlite3_get_table'"**

**"undefined reference to 'sqlite3_open'"**

I had a similar problem with the win32 build and that was solved by adding the sqlite library in Visual Studio.
Guess it's the similar problem now but I have no idea how to solve that in Eclipse?

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project

Comment: Hey, thanks but from what I understand it's only for adding Jar libraries?

Comment: AFAIK, not only jars, but you can add all supported library types.

Comment: I downloaded a sqlite jar lib to try out that solution but that didn't solve my problem so it seems like there is something else that is wrong.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394441/ndk-build-with-sqlite-library-error

Comment: Yes, could have been helpful but I have already added sqlite3.c to the Android.mk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help sithereal.
Not sure what was wrong in my Android.mk file but I wiped out the file and used another template that solved the problem.

My Android.mk do now look like this.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                    ../../Classes/x.cpp \
                    ../../Classes/y.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp\
                ../../Classes/sqlite3.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes                   

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)
```

And everything is working fine.